# Why UNIX socket files end with and equal sign in ls?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ls, sockets

When I list (`ls`) files in directory, I see the equal sign `=` after some files. All these files in my case are UNIX domain socket files:

```
user@Debian11:~/src/unix_sock$ l

a.out*     cli_stream*  dgrm_unix_sock.server=  serv_stream*  stream_serv.c          tpf_unix_sock.server=

cli_dgrm*  dgram/       serv_dgrm*              stream_cli.c  tpf_unix_sock.client=
```

What is the reason for that?

By the way, the `ls -l` command doesn't show `=`

Comment: Answered here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107429/sign-at-the-end-of-sock-files-in-the-ls-output

Comment: You didn't run plain `ls`. You ran `l` which is probably aliased to something else in your setup (probably `ls` with a convenient set of extra options). You should see how you have `l` aliased and see what extra options it's passing to `ls`, and check the `ls` man page for what those options do. One of them is probably `-F` which adds little flag characters to the ends of file names to hint their types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your shell, type

```
alias
```

You will get a list of alliasses that you have. In your case, there is probably a line

```
alias l=`ls -F`
```

among them.

In `man ls` you will see that

```
       -F, --classify
              append indicator (one of */=>@|) to entries
```

So, that is where the `=` comes from.

Comment: And  what does it mean "classify"? It addes some symbols to specific types of file like unix domain socket? Is there any other such types of file?

Comment: @NK-cell You might want to read `info ls` for a more expansive description of the file types. On my systems the file types are not documented in `man ls`. `classify` does follow the general English definition - separate into categories based on some defined characteristic.